# Function doesn't want to remove folder

Tags: php, function, class, rmdir

All functions works except the removeIt one (blank page). Here is my code bellow :

```
class Dir {
    public function emptyIt($path) { 
        if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    if(is_file($path."/".$file)) {
                        unlink($path."/".$file);
                    } else {
                        if($handle2 = opendir($path."/".$file)) {
                            while (false !== ($file2 = readdir($handle2))) {
                                if ($file2 != "." && $file2 != "..") {
                                    unlink($path."/".$file."/".$file2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        rmdir($path."/".$file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function isEmpty($path) {
        $handle=opendir($path);
        $i=0;
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            $i++;
        }
        closedir($handle); 
        if($i>=2) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function removeIt($path) {
        if (emptyIt($path)) {
            if (rmdir($path)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 functions to make it work :

1. `isEmpty` : verify if the folder is empty
2. `emptyIt` : empty folder and subfolders
3. `removeIt` : remove folder

Any hint ?

Comment: `emptyIt` should call itself recursively when it finds a folder, in case there are more levels of nesting.

Comment: @geedubb : No, no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this will remove the `folder` and its `content` (`subfolders`)

```
system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($dir));
```

where `$dir` is the path of `folder`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you execute the program with a user that doesn't have the permissions to make changes on the folder, try executing it with root or give permissions to the current user, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this will `not` remove the `empty` `direcotires` [from php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#107233)

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
if (is_dir($dir)) {
 $objects = scandir($dir);
 foreach ($objects as $object) {
   if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
     if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
   }
 }
 reset($objects);
 rmdir($dir);
}
}
```